# How can I amend individual page sizes within a pdf using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

We send a PDF directly to a label printer for printing. The printer has a cutter and will cut a continuous strip of label to the appropriate length, depending on the page size. In order to save label paper, we would like to reduce the length of each page to remove any whitespace, which varies on a per page basis. I can calculate the point at which to amend the page length to, but don't know how to then do it.

I'm using Ruby on Rails. I don't mind what library I use, but am already using imagemagick and rghost so either of those would be good.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you be more specific about what you want to remove --- all white space or just at the bottom? I do not know Ruby or RMagick, but if you want to remove all surrounding white space in an image using command line, the `convert input -fuzz XX% -trim +repage output` will do it. If you just want to remove some space at the bottom of the image, then `convert input -gravity south -chop 0x100 ouput` will chop off the bottom 100 pixels. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

Comment: That's exactly what I have done to work out what the new page dimensions should be. I've got a copy which is one image per page just to work out the dimensions. What I want to be to do is to apply those new dimensions to the original pdf pages.

Comment: I've added a bounty so I'll be clear about what I'm looking for as an appropriate answer. Assume a pdf is loaded via some library. Loop through each of the pages and apply a (potentially) different custom dimension to each. I only need to amend the length but I guess that doesn't specifically matter. The something to output/save the amended pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to resize the pages assuming that each page has an image. I hope I understand correctly.

I used [HexaPDF](https://github.com/gettalong/hexapdf).

To run as a ruby project:

1. mkdir foo
2. cd foo
3. bundle init
4. Add `gem 'hexapdf'` to Gemfile
5. bundle
6. Create `amend.rb` file

   ```
   # amend.rb
   require 'hexapdf'

   pdf = HexaPDF::Document.open(ARGV[0])
   # page_dimensions = { page_index => { w: content_width (image), h: content_height (image) } }
   page_dimensions = { 0 => { w: 323, h: 115 }, 1 => { w: 504, h: 709 }, 2 => { w: 432, h: 443 } }
   padding = 70 # You can change it if you want
   pdf.pages.each do |page|
     media_box = page.box.value.dup
     # With media_box, you can set the page dimensions.
     # [left, bottom, right, top]
     # Bottom left values: [0, 0, 0, 0]
     # A4 page dimensions: [0, 0, 595, 842]
     media_box[1] = media_box[3] - page_dimensions[page.index][:h] - 2 * padding
     media_box[2] = page_dimensions[page.index][:w] + 2 * padding
     page[:MediaBox] = media_box
   end
   pdf.write(ARGV[1])
   ```
7. Add your PDF file to `foo` directory. Let's call it `X.pdf`
8. Run program

   ```
   ruby amend.rb X.pdf X_new.pdf
   ```
9. Check `X_new.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) gem.

After installing the gem, you can try my example code in your rails console.

The following example, sets different page dimensions for even and odd pages. You can obviously put your logic there.

lets set the path of these two variables according to your system directory:

```
pdf_path = "/Users/apple/Desktop/a.pdf"
new_pdf_path = "/Users/apple/Desktop/b.pdf"
```

you can give desired dimensions in the following format:
`cropped_size = [X_min, Y_min, X_max, Y_max]`

I have used two different arrays for dimensions but you can also any dynamic params in *page.crop*

```
cropped_size_1 = [0, 0, 400, 400]
cropped_size_2 = [300, 300, 800, 800]

updated_pdf = CombinePDF.new(pdf_path)
updated_pdf.pages.each_with_index do |page, index|
  if index % 2 == 0
    page.crop(cropped_size_1)
  else
    page.crop(cropped_size_2)
  end
end
updated_pdf.save(new_pdf_path)
```

---

P.S: Above solution actually do cropping under cover!